# Best way to implement an Attribute-Value search interface using javascript

Tags: javascript, search, entity-attribute-value

I am looking to implement an Attribute-Value search interface for my backend; somewhat like AWS - EC2 search as shown in the linked gif below.

http://i.imgur.com/KDf7Cqg.gifv

Are there any existing implementations in javascript that I can use as a reference?

Edit: I've looked at [select2](https://select2.github.io/) but it only takes tags.

Comment: select2's search can be customized. So i'm guessing you will have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlk) seems like a good place to start.

Edit: I've found the exact solution I was looking for. It's called [visual search by Document Cloud](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/#demo)